# How can this MYSQL query be better

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has all the photos from a user. For some reason (dont care why) some users can be deleted (using DELETE FROM) from the users table, but the photos are kept on the photos tables.

I need to know how many photos are from users that actually exists on the users table.

The first solution I came up with is this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM photos WHERE user_id IN (SELECT id FROM users)
```

But I'm not sure if doing two Queries is the best one. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

The best way to do this would be to use a foriegn key constraint between the two tables, and implement cascading deletes.  More info available in the MySQL manual:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

As commenters have pointed out, this requires the use of the InnoDB storage engine.  [This is the default storage engine as of MySQL 5.5.5.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-engines.html)

Comment: It will be good if you add additional info that it require InnoDB engine.

Comment: I agree that foreigns keys should be used here. But for some reason the original guy who did it didn't use them.

Answer (score 2):

**Cascading delete in MyISAM**

To expand on AJ's answer. If you don't want to alter the table. Or you don't have InnoDB tables.
You can still have cascading deletes.

Put a `after delete` trigger on the leading table and put code in like this:

**You *can* have y'r cake and eat her too**

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER ad_users_each AFTER DELETE ON users FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM photos WHERE photos.user_id = old.id;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Voila, cascading deletes in MyISAM.

**How does it work?**
The trigger fires after **each** successful deletion of a row in table users.
The `old` virtual table in the triggers holds the value of `users.id` before it was deleted. I use that id to find all the matching `user_id` in table `photos` and delete those that are/were linked to the now deleted user.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find out how many non-orphaned pictures you have, you don't need `DISTINCT` at all.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM users u
INNER JOIN photos p ON (p.user_id = p.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your query does **not** return the number of photos added by users that actually exist in the users table - instead, it returns the number of users from the users table having at least one matching row in the photos table.

This query should be equivalent (might be better, might be worse performance-wise though):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) 
FROM photos, users
WHERE photos.user_id = users.id
```

If you really need the number of photos added by users that exist in the users table:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM photos, users
WHERE photos.user_id = users.id
```

assuming you don't have duplicate user ids.

Comment: `count(*)` is always faster than `count(some_field)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this sql query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM photos p
        INNER JOIN users u
            ON p.user_id = u.user_id
```